# Surfaceview to draw Thread error NULLPointerException

Tags: java, android, multithreading, nullpointerexception, surfaceview

I'm a beginner in android. I'm creating a simple surface view to draw a thread (draw rectangle), but it keeps getting error like this :

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int)' on a null object reference

and this is my code :

myActivity.java :

```
public class myActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

mySurfaceView mysurfaceview;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_ball);

    //mysurfaceview = new mySurfaceView(this);
    mysurfaceview = (mySurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mySurfaceView);
    mysurfaceview.RunThread();
 }
```

mySurfaceview.java :

```
public class mySurfaceView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

public DrawThread DrawThread;
private Rect myrectangle;
private Paint myPaint;

int moveX = 0;

private void init() {
    myrectangle = new Rect(150, 150, 700, 500);
    myPaint = new Paint();
    myPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
}

public mySurfaceView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    //init();
}

public mySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle){ super(context, attrs, defStyle); }

public mySurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { super(context, attrs); }

public void onDrawSomething(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
    canvas.drawRect(myrectangle, myPaint);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) { }

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) { }

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) { }

public void update(){
}

public void RunThread() {
    init();
    DrawThread = new DrawThread(getHolder(), this);
    DrawThread.setRunning(true);
    DrawThread.start();
}

public class DrawThread extends Thread {
    //var definition
    public boolean run = false;
    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    mySurfaceView mysurfaceView;

    public DrawThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, mySurfaceView mysurfaceView) {
        this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
        this.mysurfaceView = mysurfaceView;
    }

    public void setRunning(boolean run) {
        this.run = run;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(run)
        {
            //implement fps counter
            Canvas canvas = null;
            try {
                canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    mysurfaceView.onDrawSomething(canvas);
                    //mysurfaceView.update();
                }
            } finally {
                if(canvas != null)
                {
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And this is my XML code to show surface view :

```
 <com.example.firstapp_aurelia.mySurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/mySurfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

Did I do anything wrong here? Thank you so much.

Comment: Your question would be much better if you included the traceback.  It's very likely that the traceback points almost exactly to the problem.  That said, it looks like your question as-is was good enough to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't run you code but do not initial mySurfaceView twice

```
mysurfaceview = new mySurfaceView(this);
mysurfaceview = (mySurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.mySurfaceView);
```

Comment: Ah sorry my bad, i forget to comment `mysurfaceview = new mySurfaceView(this);`, it supposed to be comment. But even though I comment it, the app keep getting the same error.

Comment: don't try to draw anything in other thread, manipulate the canvas object in UI thread and update your logic in the background thread